# adding prefix column names that start with number in scala

Tags: scala

I have a column name starts with number, is there away that can put a prefix _ for multiple column names? I know how to replace all digits with _

```
>  val actualDF = df
  .columns
  .foldLeft(df) { (memoDF, colName) =>
    memoDF
      .withColumnRenamed(
        colName,
        colName.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\d+", "_")
      )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear. You want to add an underscore `_` prefix to all column names that start with a number, but those that don't start with a number should be left unchanged?

```
.replaceAll("^(\\d)", "_$1")
```